# File Manager issue after recent update

Tags: gui, startx

I recently updated my raspi which is running debian buster (version 10). After the update/upgrade cycle - which took a while since I have not updated my device in quite some time - I noticed an issue with startx.

Once I'm on the GUI and i double-click to open a directory, the directory will open for a second, long enough to see it has contents, but then it closes. This only occurs with directories, I can run a web-browser, text files, image viewers, etc with no problem.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this please.

Comment: It sounds like your File Manager is crashing. Nothing related to `startx`. You should edit your title to something like "file manager crashing"

Comment: Actually I'm having this issue too. Will do some troubleshooting.

Comment: @Botspot thank you for the info. I'm still learning much of linux so I'm not too familiar with what's what

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me:

```
rm -r /home/pi/.config/libfm
rm -r /home/pi/.config/pcmanfm
sudo reboot
```

And then the third one reboots your Pi (necessary)

Those first two rm commands remove the file manager's configuration.
See more at my [thread question](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=277352).

Comment: will removing those directories cause any lasting issues? Will I have to re-add/rebuild them after the reboot? I'm still learning linux so I'm not fully oriented with all of its components.

Comment: Also, reading through the libfm file, is there a way to troubleshoot which line may be causing the error?

Comment: Good questions. No, you won't have to rebuild your config structure after you delete it. Master copies of the config is mainly located in `/etc`. To illustrate my point, a never-booted RaspiOS image does not even have the `/home/pi/.config` folder! It's all generated when you launch the program.

Comment: I have no idea what is wrong with libfm's config, or pcmanfm's config. I don't even know if those first two steps are necessary! Maybe just a reboot would have been enough.

Comment: I can confirm that just a reboot does not resolve the issue. I will try removing the said directories momentarily. Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: Unfortunately running those commands did not resolve the issue. It reset my desktop environment (background image etc) but the directories closing after opening them still persists

Comment: @CLopes1987 - Do all diectories close, or only certain ones? Mine were very consistent (always Pictures, but never Documents)

Comment: yes all directories close. I tested two new directores: i created one from the commandline and another from the gui. I read through your post about the 'icons' being the issue, but these directories were empty and they closed as well

Comment: @CLopes1987 Try renaming your entire .cache folder and reboot. No different? Try renaming your .config folder too & reboot.

Comment: sorry for the late reply... i was having other issues alongside this one so i wound up reformatting the micro-sd and reinstalling raspian. thank you for all the help though!!!